# Trouble updating flatList on the first screen, when some item from the flatlist is deleted in the second screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am having trouble updating `flatList` on the first screen when some item from the `flatlist` is deleted or added on the second screen to the `flatlist`. My `flatlist` is of bands and when I click on the individual name I see the details like band members, songs, albums, etc. I've two screens currently, the home screen with a list and add or delete screen, where items on the list can be customized. This is what I have so far, but I can't manage to update the list on the main page when something is removed on the second page from the list.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, Button, Alert, Modal, TextInput, ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function UselessTextInput(props) {
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      style={{ height: 30, borderWidth: 1, padding: 6, paddingTop: 10, margin: 5, color: '#FFFCD3', borderColor: '#A5C9FA', }}
      editable
      maxLength={30}
    />
  ); t
}

const musiciansArray = [
  { id: 1, key: 'A', value: 'Pink Floyd', members: 4, songs: 165 },
  { id: 2, key: 'B', value: 'Deep Purple', members: 5, songs: 70 },
  { id: 3, key: 'C', value: 'AC/DC', members: 5, songs: 80 },[![enter image description here][1]][1]
];


function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(musiciansArray);

  const [store1, setStore1] = useState("");

  const [idDeleteInput, setIdDeleteInput] = useState();

  //const [exampleArray, setExampleArray] = useState(musiciansArray);

  const ItemView = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text
          style={styles.item}
          onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
          {item.value}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.fList} />
    );
  };
  const EmptyListMessage = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Text
        style={styles.emptyListStyle}
        onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
        Empty list found.
      </Text>
    );
  };

  const getItem = (item) => {
    alert(' id: ' + item.id + '\n' + ' key: ' + item.key + '\n' + ' Band Name: ' + item.value + '\n' + ' Members: ' + item.members + '\n' + ' Songs: ' + item.songs)
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.post) {
      setListItems(JSON.parse(route.params?.post).nameOfBand);
    }
  }, [route.params?.post]);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View >
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text1}>Bands</Text>
          <FlatList
            data={listItems}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
            renderItem={ItemView}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            ListEmptyComponent={EmptyListMessage} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.fixToText}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button2}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Input')}
            activeOpacity={0.6}
            underlayColor='red'
          >
            <Text style={styles.textButton}>Add or Delete</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
function InputScreen({ navigation,route }) {
  const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(musiciansArray);

  const [nameOfBand, setNameOfBand] = useState('');
  const [keyOfBand, setkeyOfBand] = useState('');
  const [memInput2, setMemInput2] = useState('');
  const [songInput2, setSongInput2] = useState('');

  const [idDeleteInput, setIdDeleteInput] = useState();
  const [idDeleteInput2, setIdDeleteInput2] = useState();


  const [exampleArray, setExampleArray] = useState(musiciansArray);

  const delItem = () => {
    navigation.navigate('InputScreen', { post: JSON.stringify({ text: idDeleteInput2 }) });
    if (idDeleteInput2 > musiciansArray.length || idDeleteInput2 === "" || isNaN(idDeleteInput2)) {
      Alert.alert('No such id is present.');
    } else if (exampleArray.length === 0) {
      Alert.alert('Nothing can be deleted, empty list found.');
    }
    else {
      Alert.alert("Item with id " + idDeleteInput2 + " sucessfully deleted.");
      const filteredArray = exampleArray.filter(item => item.id != idDeleteInput2);
      setExampleArray(filteredArray);
    }
  }

  const alertAdd = () => {
    navigation.navigate('InputScreen', { post: JSON.stringify({ text: nameOfBand, text: keyOfBand , text: memInput2 ,text: songInput2  }) });
   
    if (nameOfBand == "" || keyOfBand == "" || memInput2 == "" || songInput2 == "") {
      Alert.alert("No new item has been added, as atleast a field is empty.");
    } else {
      var newArray = [...exampleArray, { id: exampleArray.length + 1, key: keyOfBand, value: nameOfBand, members: memInput2, songs: songInput2 }];
      setExampleArray(newArray);
      Alert.alert("Item " + nameOfBand + " added successfully.");
    }
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text3}>Add</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text4}>Band Name:</Text>
        <UselessTextInput
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={nameOfBand}
          onChangeText={itemText => setNameOfBand(itemText)}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text4}>Key e.g. A, B, C:</Text>
        <UselessTextInput
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={keyOfBand}
          onChangeText={itemText => setkeyOfBand(itemText)}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text4}>No. of Members:</Text>
        <UselessTextInput
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={memInput2}
          onChangeText={itemText => setMemInput2(itemText)}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text4}>No. of Songs:</Text>
        <UselessTextInput
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={songInput2}
          onChangeText={itemText => setSongInput2(itemText)}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.fixToText}>
        {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={alertAdd}
          style={styles.button2}>
          <Text style={styles.textButton}>Press To Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
        <TouchableOpacity
          // onPress={alertAdd}
          onPress={alertAdd}
          // Pass params back to home screen
          style={styles.button2}>
          <Text style={styles.textButton}>Press To Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>

      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text3}>Delete</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text4}>Id to delete:</Text>
        <UselessTextInput
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={idDeleteInput2}
          onChangeText={delID => setIdDeleteInput2(delID)} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.fixToText2}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={delItem}
          style={styles.button3}>
          <Text style={styles.textButton}>Press To Del</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Input" component={InputScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is what my app looks like right now:

[image: Home screen]
[image: Input screen]
I know this is a lot of code, but I have mentioned the gist of the concept here, I am probably missing something here regarding navigation, as I am pretty new to that concept. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for screen not being updated is when you are navigating back to the screen, the screen is not re rendered as it is already rendered. The changes made on the second screen doesn't re renders the previous screen. In case to achieve that, if you are using react navigation then there is a option to add Event Listener for screen focus, you can use that event to update your screen.

See: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/